# A comma and a semicolon in For

Tags: output-formatting

Here is the first one.

```
i = 1; For[t = x, i^2 < 10, i++; t = t^2 + i, Print[t]]
```

This will output

```
x
2+x^2
3+(2+x^2)^2
```

But I thought the result would be like this.

```
x 
x^2+1 
(x^2+1)^2+2
```

However, when I input this.

```
For[t = x, i = 1; i^2 < 10, i++, t = t^2 + i; Print[t]]
```

This will never ends and produce such a result below.

```
1+x^2
1+(1+x^2)^2
1+(1+(1+x^2)^2)^2
1+(1+(1+(1+x^2)^2)^2)^2
1+(1+(1+(1+(1+x^2)^2)^2)^2)^2
1+(1+(1+(1+(1+(1+x^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2
...
...
...
```

**What's the wrong with this?
Why is `i=1` all the time ?
I thought `i` will change every time.**

Comment: You added `i=1` to the test. The test is executed in every iteration of the loop. In every iteration, `i` is reset to be 1. Write it like this to make sure commas and semicolons aren't confused:  `For[(t = x),  (i = 1; i^2 < 10),  (i++),  (t = t^2 + i; Print[t])]`  Commas separate, semicolons join.

Comment: See also [`CompoundExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says:

```
WolframLanguageData["For", "PlaintextUsage"]
```

> "For[start, test, incr, body] executes start, then repeatedly evaluates body 
> and incr until test fails to give True."

So, your test is:

```
i = 1; i^2 < 10
```

and this test is always true.

Comment: How about the first one?`i = 1; For[t = x, i^2 < 10, i++; t = t^2 + i, Print[t]]` . I thought the result would be  ```x , x^2+1,(x^2+1)^2+2```

Comment: If` `i = 1; i^2 < 10` is the case, the result(output) will be `1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...` and so on.